How to save file in algorithm window in QGIS
When I was using the following hillside tool from the "processing" and wanted to save it (as shown as follows), this tool's window would close automatically after I clicked "save", without running the algorithm. I wasn't able to save it neither.
I encountered the same problem when I used different tools. How I can save when I create the layer? When I wanted to save it in this way, the window just closed and it wasn't saved and the algorithm didn't run neither.


You are selecting Hillshade as an input elevation layer, which is incorrect. You should choose a DEM input layer. If you still encounter a problem running the tool. Try to uninstall QGIS completely from your machine and reinstall it back again.

can you also provide the version of QGIS you are running and the OS you are running it on.

If you want to export the temporary Hillshade layer to a file, select it in the Layers panel and go to menu Layer, Save As...
You can also right-click on the layer and select Export in the contextual menu, Save As...
If you want to run a Hillshade algorithm, but send the output to a file instead of a temporary layer, then you can click on the ... button and select Save To File... in the dialog output parameter, as in your screenshot.
The algorithm window must not close, but a system file dialog must open. In which you can select a folder and a file type, and write the file name to be saved. When you click Save in the system file dialog, it closes. The focus must return to the algorithm dialog and the path to the file must be written in the output parameter instead of the [Save to temporary file] text.
Then, you can Run the algorithm, and its output will be saved to the choosen file.
It is possible that there is a problem opening the system file dialog, since it is something articulated between QGIS, the Qt library and the operating system. In which case it is very likely that someone before you has discovered the problem and found the reason and solution to it.
But your question seems more intended to understand and differentiate what the mechanisms of exporting temporary layers and saving algorithm outputs to files are like in QGIS. And in the event that something is failing understand what normal behavior would be like, to know what is wrong and to be able to find a solution.
